# I need all the columns from table1 and table 2 which have duplicate data

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables table1 and table2
ex: **table 1**

```
id1     name1    fatherName1    village1    category1    subcategory1  
1,        a,       x1,          v1,          c1,           sc1   
2,        b,       x2,          v2,          c2,           sc2   
3,        a,       x1,          v1,          c3,           sc3  
4,        c,       x4,          v4,          c4,            sc4
```

**table2**

```
id2     name2   fatherName2  village2  category2   subcategory2  
1,        a,      x1,            v1,        c5,        sc5   
2,        b,      x2,            v2,        c2,        sc2  
3,        c,      x5,            v5,        c3,        sc3  
4,        d,      x6,           v6,         c6,        sc6
```

Above I have mentioned 6 columns and 4 rows of the table.
Now, I need

```
all the rows table1 and table2 where 
(table1.name1=table2.name2 
and table1.fatherName1= table2.fateherName2 
and table1.village1=table2.village2) 
OR (table1.name1=table1.name1 
and table1.fatherName1= table1.fateherName1 
and table1.village1=table1.village1)
```

You can answer it either by java or sql whichever you like. Guys please help me out....thanx in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't you tried a `SELECT` statement and put that condition in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Just join table1 and table2 on relevant columns

Comment: I tried to edit my answer but there're still a lot possibilities how your result might look like. Could you please edit your post and add the result set that you want to achieve with the two example tables?

Answer (score 0):

i guess that you can use 'union' and 'distinct' to do what u want to do :)

Comment: I used simple join but I need  duplicate data from both the tables as well as table 1

Comment: use **`select distinct`**

Comment: I need to compare each row of table1 with table 1 itself and table 2 and get all the data which i compare and which matched. Then I have to display them on jsp in three rows

Comment: row1 >>> Data which I compared from table1(single row) row>>2 data which matched in table2(here can be multiple rows)  and row>>3 data which matched in table1 itself(here also can be multiple rows)

Comment: 'table1.name1=table1.name1 
and table1.fatherName1= table1.fateherName1 
and table1.village1=table1.village1' what do you mean? this paragraph is always true?!

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls680.htm). Besides that I will give you partial answer :
Your query should be like this :

```
Query = "Select * from table1 t1,table2 t2 where (YOUR CONDITION COMES HERE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at your question and wonder why you ask, because you have the answer formulated yourself (at least the where-clause of it).

```
select *
from   table1, table2
where (table1.name1=table2.name2 
and table1.fatherName1 = table2.fatherName2
and table1.village1=table2.village2
) OR 
(table1.name1=table1.name1 
and table1.fatherName1= table1.fatherName1 
and table1.village1=table1.village1)
```

Comment: acyually I need mapping for each data of table 1 to matched data of table1 AND TABLE 2

Comment: With your first comment I understand that I've understood your question only in parts. Can you please add the outcome you want to achieve to your question? I think you would then get better answers - not only from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
      (select t1.id1 as id,t1.name1 as name from table1 t1 inner join t2 on (t1.name1=t2.name2 and t1.fatherName1=t2.fatherName2 and t1.village1=t2.village2))
        union all
      (select t2.id2 as id,t2.name2 as name from table2 t2 inner join t1 on (t1.name1=t2.name2 and t1.fatherName1=t2.fatherName2 and t1.village1=t2.village2))
```

Comment: i need all the columns

Comment: add all columns to select list yourself; I didn't do that because is trivial adding them